# GIMP 2.8.16, weird bug cursor aligning to grid, windows 7

Tags: gimp, snapping, pixel-grid

Whenever I am trying to draw/paint in gimp my cursor seems to be snapping to every other pixel or two?

[image]
Brush size of 4px, I would like it to be smooth when I draw.

I should note, this only appears to be happening in Windows 7, I do not have this issue on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Which sections of the GIMP user manual have you read in order to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but since you mentioned "grid", it looks like literally "snapping" to some grid is activated. Try disabling whatever "snap to" option may be enabled in the "View" menu.

Comment: I feel like an idiot completely overlooked view menu...